# How to input Array's value one by one to database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I would like to get an input from the form as an Array (the values are **members_id**) and then iterate the values of it to insert them to my Attendance table (which has event_id column and member_id column).

The models:

```rb
class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :member
end
```

AttendancesController#create:

```rb
    def create
      @attendance = Attendance.new(attendance_params)
      if @attendance.save
        redirect_to events_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    private

    def attendance_params
      params.require(:attendance).permit(:event_id, member_id: [])
    end
```

And then the Form:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @attendance do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :event,
        label: "Event",
        error: "Event must be chosen!",
        collection: Event.all.order(:name),
        label_method: :name,
        prompt: "-Choose Event-" %>
    <%= f.association :member,
        error: "Members must be chosen!",
        label: false,
        as: :check_boxes,
        label_method: lambda { |m| "<span>#{m.name}</span><br >".html_safe },
        include_hidden: false  %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Save Data", class: "btn-margin-r-10", style: "margin-top: 15px;" %>
<% end %>
```

I used the dropdown input for the Event because users can only edit one Event's attendance data. And for the Members, I used checkboxes because one Event could be attended by lots of Members.
But when I tried to Submit the form, it failed to save the data.

The question is, how do I iterate the `member_ids` array so I can save them one by one?
Thanks

Comment: Your `Attendance` model takes a `member_id` but you're passing it an array for member_id instead of one single integer value. In your `Attendance` model you will have to write a custom method that loops over every `member_id` in the params and create a separate `attendance` instance for it. You will have to call this new method in the controller instead of `Attendance.create`

Comment: @MoizMansur Did you mean I'll have to use a new method in the controller instead of `Attendance.save` in attendances#create?

Comment: Yes, call the newly created method in the controller instead of `Attendance.create`

Comment: @MoizMansur I really appreciate your help, but currently I'm still stuck at creating the method in my Model. I'm very sorry to ask you again, but do you have any reference for that? Thank you.